# is different word embedding methods can produce same vocabulary in a same dataset.?

Tags: python, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, data-preprocessing

I want to ask about why my embedding matrices have different dimension each other.
first I using word2vec on IMDB dataset and produce around 17620 vocabulary without using any stop words. secondly I using glove on same dataset and produce around 193093 vocabulary. and last using fast text on same dataset and produce around 222422 vocabulary. is there any some trick to make it same number on vocabulary..?
thanks' for any help.

creating corpus

```py
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
nltk.download("punkt")
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
train_size = int(train.shape[0] * 0.9)

def create_corpus_tk(df):
    corpus = []
    for text in df["text"]:
        words = [word.lower() for word in word_tokenize(text)]
        corpus.append(words)
    return corpus

corpus = create_corpus_tk(train[:train_size])
```

tokenizer code

```py
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=num_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(corpus)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print("Number of unique words:", len(word_index))
```

w2v code

```py
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec(corpus, sg=1, min_count=1, window=10, vector_size=100)
print(model)
words = list(model.wv.index_to_key)
print(len(words))
```

fast text code

```py
from gensim.models import FastText
modelFS = FastText(corpus, sg=1, min_count=1, window=10, vector_size=100)
words = list(modelFS.wv.index_to_key)
print(len(words))
```

glove code

```py
embedding_dict = {}
with open(os.getcwd()+"\\ready\\glove.twitter.27B.100d.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split()
        word = values[0]
        vectors = np.asarray(values[1:], "float32")
        embedding_dict[word] = vectors
f.close()

num_words = len(word_index)
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((num_words, 100))

for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i < num_words:
        emb_vec = embedding_dict.get(word)
        if emb_vec is not None:
            embedding_matrix[i] = emb_vec
```

Comment: are all three programs designed for the same purpose?

Comment: which number is the correct one?

Comment: the purpose of all programs is to create word embedding matrix that will be feed into the model architecture. but I wonder why they produce different vocabulary numbers even though they use the same dataset. in dataset sum of all word is 5992616 and the unique word is 208259

Comment: It'd be good to post your code, for each case, that produces that vocabulary; then we can see the exact parameters being used. (Or if you are exactly following a publicly available tutorial or example for each, then giving the URL you used.) 
They tend to have a `min_count` parameter. Also remember that fast text is operating at the sub word level.

Comment: @DarrenCook okay, I've already add it